# First float from a string full of garbage in Python?

Tags: python, string, floating-point

what is the cleanest way to get the first valid float number (I consider int as a valid float) from a string of random garbage?

```
"jkyf- skj7eio9.00" -> 7.0
"r-9.98989 8JHGJHG" -> -9.98989
"kjg-§ejjkv" -> None (or some other indication that no float was found)
```

etc? Is it possible without loading re module?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to avoid the `re` module?

Comment: loop every char, analyse yourself. Best I can think of.

Comment: not real reason, I just want to know the simplest solution, I often find that I am doing things in much more complicated way than necessary

Comment: Note that regular expressions exist for a reason. This might be a case where regular expressions ARE the simplest solution.

Comment: if so, I have no problem with it, but for me it still looks little bit like a black magic :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `float(substring)` for every substring, until you find one:

```
In [24]: def get_first_float(s):
   ....:     for start in range(len(s)):
   ....:         for end in range(len(s), start, -1):
   ....:             try:
   ....:                 return float(s[start:end])
   ....:             except ValueError:
   ....:                 pass
   ....: 

In [25]: get_first_float("jkyf- skj7eio9.00")
Out[25]: 7.0

In [26]: get_first_float("r-9.98989 8JHGJHG")
Out[26]: -9.98989

In [27]: get_first_float("kjg-§ejjkv")

In [28]: get_first_float("Even finds 1e6, One Million!")
Out[28]: 1000000.0

In [29]:
```

Comment: I have a utility function `floatify` which does much the same.  Sure it's inefficient, but it's robust, doesn't require borrowing an incomprehensible regex, is fast enough in practice, and comes in very handy.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (untested, because unpythonic approach in the first place if you want to avoid `re`). A potential `-` sign is not recognized, but you should be able to include that as well.

```
nums = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
firstfloat=[]
scanning = False
for letter in string:
  if letter in nums:
    firstfloat.append(letter)
    scanning = True
  if letter == '.' and scanning:
    firstfloat.append('.')
    continue

  if scanning and letter not in nums:
    break

print(''.join(firstfloat))
```

Comment: This probably won't recognize negative numbers, will it? But I can imagine how to fix it. But re would be probably indeed better.

Comment: `-1`
a) In python `Python 3.4.2` command `'1' in (1,2)` evaluates as `False`
b) Your example fails at `1.2.3.4`
c) Your example doesn't handle `-`
*d) Not using `elif`*

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I've just noticed that you want to avoid using `re`.

```
import re

strings = ['jkyf- skj7eio9.00',
'jkyf- skj6.90.90eio9.00',
'r-9.98989 8JHGJHG',
'kjg-jejjkv']

regex = r'[+-]?(\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)([eE][+-]?\d+)?'

for s in strings:
    found = re.findall(regex,s)
    # print found
    if len(found) > 0:
        print float(found[0][0])
```

Comment: this fails on the first string (should find 7, but finds 9), and on the second one as well, it does not recognize the negative sign

Comment: @nekomimi Modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I read this post a few mins ago and thought I'd give it a shot so here's what I came up with:

```
values = set('1234567890.-')
a = "jkyf- skj7eio9.00"
for i in range(100):
    b = ''.join(ch for ch in a if ch in values)
print(b)
```

Hope this helped,

~bobbeh

Comment: okay, just re-read the question and noticed that i read it wrong the first time xD